# Incorrect item width after batch/unbatch

Tags: anylogic

i am trying to transport a batch of 2 boxes form a conveyor to anotherone with the help of an AGV.
Without the batch block its workling flawless, but the agv can only tranport a single box by time, thats why the batch block come into play.
The AGV picks up the batch of two boxes and when it wants to unload them on the next conveyor AnyLogic  displays the following error message.

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UQdUe.png)

[Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EVO2k.png)

And the two boxes are not wider then the conveyor.

[Boxes on conveyor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cpE3P.png)

[spreadsheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7avfp.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was located in the batch blog.
Because I set the dimentisons in the agent, I did not think about changing them **but** when not clicking at the checkbox *change dimensions* and actually set them to the parameters to the real ones the dimensions will be set to 1 meter, in height, width and lengh independent from the dimensions of the agent.
I discovered this as I let output the with of the agent on the console, when it was moved to the AGV.

[Configuration Batch Blog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SZepE.png)